# Embedded ActiveMQ Artemis is stopped before end of test

Tags: spring, spring-batch, activemq-artemis

I am trying to put messages on a queue with Spring Batch (jmsitemwriter) but the ActiveMQ server is stopped before I can readout the queue.

```
import BatchTestJmsInMemoryConfig;
import TestDatabase;
import import org.apache.activemq.artemis.junit.EmbeddedActiveMQExtension;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.RegisterExtension;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.test.context.SpringBatchTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsOperations;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;
import org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.Sql;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBatchTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BatchTestJmsInMemoryConfig.class})
@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-h2.properties")
@Sql(scripts = {
        "/sql/initial-setup-batch-tables.sql",
        "/sql/initial-setup-log-and-employer-quarter-table.sql",
        "/sql/testcases/168100417.sql"
})
@DirtiesContext
class Employer168100417IntegrationTest {

    private final static String EMPLOYER_ID = "168100417";
    private final Path basePath = Paths.get("src/test/resources/csv/testcases");

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
    @Autowired
    private TestDatabase testDatabase;
    @RegisterExtension
    public EmbeddedActiveMQExtension server = new EmbeddedActiveMQExtension();

    @Test
    void testSetup() throws IOException {
        jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("sendEvents");
        System.out.println(server.getMessageCount("queue"));

    }

}
```

```
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

@Import(BatchTestConfiguration.class)
@Configuration
public class BatchTestJmsInMemoryConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://0?broker.useShutdownHook=false");
    }

}
```

The output is this and you can see that the server is shutdown before I can query the number of items of the queue

```
2023-11-24T13:26:41.659+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-11-24T13:26:42.314+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:batchDataSource user=SA
2023-11-24T13:26:42.317+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-11-24T13:26:42.428+01:00  WARN   --- [           main] ocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer : Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: be.smals.employerregistry.declarationsfollowup.declarationsfollowupbatch.config.BatchConfiguration
2023-11-24T13:26:42.915+01:00  WARN   --- [           main] ocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer : Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: be.smals.employerregistry.declarationsfollowup.declarationsfollowupbatch.writers.Writers
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
2023-11-24T13:26:44.535+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=TestJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{'random':'{value=6155502824501581573, type=class java.lang.Long, identifying=true}'}]
2023-11-24T13:26:44.568+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [sendSilencersToInspectionServiceStep]
2023-11-24T13:26:44.600+01:00 DEBUG   --- [           main] b.s.e.d.d.p.FetchSilencersForNossNumber  : Finding all silencer records for employer 168100417
2023-11-24T13:26:44.613+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] b.s.e.d.d.processors.AggregateQuarters   : Aggregating quarters for silencer 168100417 with 3 eventBlocks: [[YearQuarter[year=2003, quarter=1]..YearQuarter[year=2003, quarter=2]], [YearQuarter[year=2003, quarter=4]..YearQuarter[year=2003, quarter=4]], [YearQuarter[year=2004, quarter=3]..YearQuarter[year=2004, quarter=3]]]
2023-11-24T13:26:44.622+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] b.s.e.d.d.w.SendSilencerEventsWriter     : Delegating the following event blocks to JmsItemWriter to send to eventbus [SilencerEvents.EventBlock(quarterRange=[YearQuarter[year=2003, quarter=1]..YearQuarter[year=2003, quarter=2]], eventReference=77716a04-6062-467b-8caa-7d6c422fe42f, employerId=168100417), SilencerEvents.EventBlock(quarterRange=[YearQuarter[year=2003, quarter=4]..YearQuarter[year=2003, quarter=4]], eventReference=fc6974f6-2079-4696-a446-90830e7d7f04, employerId=168100417), SilencerEvents.EventBlock(quarterRange=[YearQuarter[year=2004, quarter=3]..YearQuarter[year=2004, quarter=3]], eventReference=04601426-8762-4354-8d21-2f1bf097a9b5, employerId=168100417)]
2023-11-24T13:26:44.623+01:00 DEBUG   --- [           main] o.s.batch.item.jms.JmsItemWriter         : Writing to JMS with 3 items.
2023-11-24T13:26:44.797+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[C:\Users\kjm\Source\declarations-follow-up-batch\activemq-data\0\KahaDB]
2023-11-24T13:26:44.798+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Starting Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[C:\Users\kjm\Source\declarations-follow-up-batch\activemq-data\0\KahaDB]
2023-11-24T13:26:44.812+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.a.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore    : Starting KahaDBStore
2023-11-24T13:26:44.813+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.a.a.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase       : Opening MessageDatabase
2023-11-24T13:26:44.856+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.a.a.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase       : KahaDB is version 7
2023-11-24T13:26:44.926+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Starting Temp Data Store
2023-11-24T13:26:44.927+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.a.a.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl  : PListStore:[C:\Users\kjm\Source\declarations-follow-up-batch\activemq-data\0\tmp_storage] started
2023-11-24T13:26:44.927+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Starting Job Scheduler Store
2023-11-24T13:26:44.927+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Persistence Adapter successfully started
2023-11-24T13:26:45.094+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Apache ActiveMQ 5.18.2 (0, ID:2304L6797A4-51846-1700828804945-0:1) is starting
2023-11-24T13:26:45.201+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Apache ActiveMQ 5.18.2 (0, ID:2304L6797A4-51846-1700828804945-0:1) started
2023-11-24T13:26:45.202+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
2023-11-24T13:26:45.217+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.a.activemq.broker.TransportConnector   : Connector vm://0 started
2023-11-24T13:26:45.428+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] b.s.e.d.d.e.CustomMessageConverter       : Message successfully created for employer 168100417
2023-11-24T13:26:45.428+01:00 TRACE   --- [           main] b.s.e.d.d.e.CustomMessageConverter       : message is: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, messageId = null, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = null, destination = null, transactionId = null, deliveryTime = 0, expiration = 0, timestamp = 0, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = 77716a04-6062-467b-8caa-7d6c422fe42f, replyTo = null, persistent = false, type = null, priority = 0, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = null, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {eventId=77716a04-6062-467b-8caa-7d6c422fe42f, contentSchema=content.json, creatorUrn=rsz-onss:sending:notification:sile001, payloadSchema=nonResponsiveEmployer.json, destinationTopic=socsec-033.nsso.declaration.dmfa.nonResponsiveEmployers, publisherUrn=rsz-onss:sending:notification:sile001, timestamp=2023-11-24T12:26:45Z}, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = {"contentVersion":"1.0","actor":{"isSystem":t...03-06-30"}}}}
2023-11-24T13:26:45.448+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] b.s.e.d.d.e.CustomMessageConverter       : Message successfully created for employer 168100417
2023-11-24T13:26:45.448+01:00 TRACE   --- [           main] b.s.e.d.d.e.CustomMessageConverter       : message is: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, messageId = null, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = null, destination = null, transactionId = null, deliveryTime = 0, expiration = 0, timestamp = 0, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = fc6974f6-2079-4696-a446-90830e7d7f04, replyTo = null, persistent = false, type = null, priority = 0, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = null, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {eventId=fc6974f6-2079-4696-a446-90830e7d7f04, contentSchema=content.json, creatorUrn=rsz-onss:sending:notification:sile001, payloadSchema=nonResponsiveEmployer.json, destinationTopic=socsec-033.nsso.declaration.dmfa.nonResponsiveEmployers, publisherUrn=rsz-onss:sending:notification:sile001, timestamp=2023-11-24T12:26:45Z}, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = {"contentVersion":"1.0","actor":{"isSystem":t...03-12-31"}}}}
2023-11-24T13:26:45.451+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] b.s.e.d.d.e.CustomMessageConverter       : Message successfully created for employer 168100417
2023-11-24T13:26:45.452+01:00 TRACE   --- [           main] b.s.e.d.d.e.CustomMessageConverter       : message is: ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, messageId = null, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = null, destination = null, transactionId = null, deliveryTime = 0, expiration = 0, timestamp = 0, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = 04601426-8762-4354-8d21-2f1bf097a9b5, replyTo = null, persistent = false, type = null, priority = 0, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = null, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = {eventId=04601426-8762-4354-8d21-2f1bf097a9b5, contentSchema=content.json, creatorUrn=rsz-onss:sending:notification:sile001, payloadSchema=nonResponsiveEmployer.json, destinationTopic=socsec-033.nsso.declaration.dmfa.nonResponsiveEmployers, publisherUrn=rsz-onss:sending:notification:sile001, timestamp=2023-11-24T12:26:45Z}, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false, text = {"contentVersion":"1.0","actor":{"isSystem":t...04-09-30"}}}}
2023-11-24T13:26:45.458+01:00 DEBUG   --- [           main] b.s.e.d.d.dao.SilencerLoggingDao         : Creating successful record in log table with employer id 168100417 for quarter 20031 with event reference 77716a04-6062-467b-8caa-7d6c422fe42f
2023-11-24T13:26:45.465+01:00 DEBUG   --- [           main] b.s.e.d.d.dao.SilencerLoggingDao         : Creating successful record in log table with employer id 168100417 for quarter 20032 with event reference 77716a04-6062-467b-8caa-7d6c422fe42f
2023-11-24T13:26:45.465+01:00 DEBUG   --- [           main] b.s.e.d.d.dao.SilencerLoggingDao         : Creating successful record in log table with employer id 168100417 for quarter 20034 with event reference fc6974f6-2079-4696-a446-90830e7d7f04
2023-11-24T13:26:45.466+01:00 DEBUG   --- [           main] b.s.e.d.d.dao.SilencerLoggingDao         : Creating successful record in log table with employer id 168100417 for quarter 20043 with event reference 04601426-8762-4354-8d21-2f1bf097a9b5
2023-11-24T13:26:45.466+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] ItemLogger                               : Writing SilencerEvents[employerId=168100417, events=[SilencerEvents.EventBlock(quarterRange=[YearQuarter[year=2003, quarter=1]..YearQuarter[year=2003, quarter=2]], eventReference=77716a04-6062-467b-8caa-7d6c422fe42f, employerId=168100417), SilencerEvents.EventBlock(quarterRange=[YearQuarter[year=2003, quarter=4]..YearQuarter[year=2003, quarter=4]], eventReference=fc6974f6-2079-4696-a446-90830e7d7f04, employerId=168100417), SilencerEvents.EventBlock(quarterRange=[YearQuarter[year=2004, quarter=3]..YearQuarter[year=2004, quarter=3]], eventReference=04601426-8762-4354-8d21-2f1bf097a9b5, employerId=168100417)]]
2023-11-24T13:26:45.483+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.a.activemq.broker.TransportConnector   : Connector vm://0 stopped
2023-11-24T13:26:45.484+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Apache ActiveMQ 5.18.2 (0, ID:2304L6797A4-51846-1700828804945-0:1) is shutting down
2023-11-24T13:26:45.487+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.a.a.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl  : PListStore:[C:\Users\kjm\Source\declarations-follow-up-batch\activemq-data\0\tmp_storage] stopped
2023-11-24T13:26:45.487+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.a.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore    : Stopping async queue tasks
2023-11-24T13:26:45.487+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.a.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore    : Stopping async topic tasks
2023-11-24T13:26:45.488+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.a.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore    : Stopped KahaDB
2023-11-24T13:26:45.514+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Apache ActiveMQ 5.18.2 (0, ID:2304L6797A4-51846-1700828804945-0:1) uptime 0.808 seconds
2023-11-24T13:26:45.514+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService   : Apache ActiveMQ 5.18.2 (0, ID:2304L6797A4-51846-1700828804945-0:1) is shutdown
2023-11-24T13:26:45.516+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [sendSilencersToInspectionServiceStep] executed in 946ms
2023-11-24T13:26:45.525+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=TestJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{'random':'{value=6155502824501581573, type=class java.lang.Long, identifying=true}'}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 973ms

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.ActiveMQServer.locateQueue(org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.SimpleString)" because the return value of "org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.embedded.EmbeddedActiveMQ.getActiveMQServer()" is null

    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.junit.EmbeddedActiveMQDelegate.locateQueue(EmbeddedActiveMQDelegate.java:261)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.junit.EmbeddedActiveMQDelegate.getMessageCount(EmbeddedActiveMQDelegate.java:245)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.junit.EmbeddedActiveMQDelegate.getMessageCount(EmbeddedActiveMQDelegate.java:240)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.junit.EmbeddedActiveMQExtension.getMessageCount(EmbeddedActiveMQExtension.java:175)
    at be.smals.employerregistry.declarationsfollowup.declarationsfollowupbatch.integrationtests.inmemory.Employer168100417IntegrationTest.testSetup(Employer168100417IntegrationTest.java:56)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)

2023-11-24T13:26:45.555+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-11-24T13:26:45.559+01:00  INFO   --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code -1
```

I tried everything a bit, like adding the broker.useShutdownHook=false clause but the server/broker keeps on shutting down